# Store data in a class dynamically and access data as class attributes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, oop, python-dataclasses

I am trying to write a class that takes data where the dataframe IDs as strings and the values as DataFrames and create class attributes accessing the data.

I was able to write a small example of a similar class that needs the methods to be created in a static manner and return the objects as class methods but I would like to loop over the data, taking in the keys for the `df`s and allow for access to each `df` using attributes.

**minimum working example**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

# re-writing as dataclass
@dataclass
class Dataset:

    # data container dictionary as class attribute
    dict = {'df1_id':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1]}), 
            'df2_id':pd.DataFrame({'col2':[2,2]}), 
            'df3_id':pd.DataFrame({'col3':[3,3]})}
    
    
    def df1_id(self) -> pd.DataFrame:# class method to create as class attribute
        return dict['df1_id']

    def df2_id(self) -> pd.DataFrame:# same class method above
        return dict['df2_id']

    def df3_id(self) -> pd.DataFrame:# same class method above
        return dict['df3_id']

    def dataframes_as_class_attributes(self):
        # store the dfs to access as class attributes
        # replacing 3 methods above
        return
```

**result**

```
datasets = Dataset()

print(datasets.df1_id())
```

**expected result**

```
datasets = Dataset()

print(datasets.df1_id) # class attribute created by looping through the dict object
```

Edit:

- Similar to this: [How to read the contents of a csv file into a class with each csv row as a class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47445586/how-to-read-the-contents-of-a-csv-file-into-a-class-with-each-csv-row-as-a-class)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here that just using a dictionary doesn't work? From what I can tell, what you want is doable, but it's not really something you should think too seriously about actually doing... it's not particularly Pythonic...

Comment: Hi @JonClements What would a better approach be?

Comment: I could also pull the data from CSV's ? I would like to store data using a class then allow the data to be accessed using class attributes. The number of files could vary though hence I initially stored them in a dictionary @JonClements

Comment: ... and what's the issue with just keeping the dataframes in a dictionary? It's not clear what storing them as attributes on a class you think solves?

Comment: Easy to access  the dataframes on vscode with autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setattr` like below:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import pandas as pd

@dataclass
class Dataset:

    dict_ = {'df1_id':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1]}), 
            'df2_id':pd.DataFrame({'col2':[2,2]}), 
            'df3_id':pd.DataFrame({'col3':[3,3]})}
            
    def __post_init__(self):
        for key, val in self.dict_.items():
            setattr(self, key, val)
```

To avoid conflicts with python keywords put a single trailing underscore after variable name. ([PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles))

Comment: Thank you @Czysztof, this is exactly what I was trying to do

Answer (score 1):

> taking in the keys for the `df`s and allow for access to each `df` using attributes.

It seems that the only purpose of the class is to have attribute access syntax. In that case, it would be simpler to just create a [namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) object.

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

class Dataset(SimpleNamespace):
    pass 
    # extend it possibly 

data = {
    'df1_id':pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1]}), 
    'df2_id':pd.DataFrame({'col2':[2,2]}), 
    'df3_id':pd.DataFrame({'col3':[3,3]})
}

datasets = Dataset(**data)
```

Output:

```
>>> datasets.df1_id 

   col1
0     1
1     1

>>> datasets.df2_id 

   col2
0     2
1     2

>>> datasets.df3_id 

   col3
0     3
1     3
```